# Calculating a total number of unique days of data

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a large dataset showing how people travel.  I need to calculate the amount of unique days people travel on.  The table below shows ID, which is unique to each particular person.  Associated with each ID is the dates they have travelled on - for some people this may be one trip per day, for others there may well be multiple trips on each day (e.g. person "1" took two trips on the 4th).  What I need R to do is pick out the total number of unique days for all people in the dataset (e.g. person 1 = 2, person 2=3, person 3=1, person 4=2 - therefore the total using the mini-dataset below should be 8.

```
ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4)
date = c("4th Nov","4th Nov","5th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov","8th Nov","6th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov")
data<-data.frame(ID,date)
```

Any suggestions on the coding for R would be gratefully received.

Many thanks.

Comment: As a side note, it is regarded as bad practice to reuse reserved words in R, e.g. data, date. They already have a function assigned to them. Redefining them by using that name for a dataset can lead to nasty problems.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: Technically "data" and "date" aren't reserved, which is why you can assign to them.  See `?Reserved` for a list of truly reserved words.  I agree that it is usually bad form to name variables after functions.

Comment: I see, then I'm using the term reserved a somewhat broader sense. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again a task for ddply:

```
ddply(data, .(id), summarise, noDays = length(unique(date)))

  ID noDays
1  1      2
2  2      3
3  3      1
4  4      2
```

Answer (score 5):

You should make friends with the `plyr` package.  The `ddply` function makes this bit of analysis very straight-forward.  It takes a `data.frame`, splits it according to some criterion (in this case ID), applies a function and combines the pieces intoa a `data.frame`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(ID), summarise, days=length(unique(date)))
  ID days
1  1    2
2  2    3
3  3    1
4  4    2
```

Or with base R, use `split` and `sapply` to get a vector with your desired results:

```
sapply(with(data, split(date, ID)), function(x)length(unique(x)))
1 2 3 4 
2 3 1 2
```

Comment: Hmmm, we posted within seconds of each other, with exactly the same answer. What is etiquette in this case? You had not posted when I started typing...

Comment: @PaulHiemstra You will find this happens from time to time.  I don't think there is any single accepted etiquette.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra Returned the favour :) You posted a really good answer :-)

Comment: Hmmm, feels like people who are sending each other Linkedin recommendations :)

Answer (score 5):

Also possible with `tapply` from base R.

```
with(data, tapply(date, ID, function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

As an alternative to `length(unique(x))` you can utilise the fact that `date` is a factor and count the levels.

```
with(data, tapply(date, ID, function(x) nlevels(x[, drop = TRUE])))
```

---

Bonus thoughts:

To solve your problem of defining a variable called "date", note that you can include vectors in your call to data.frame, like so.

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4),
  date = c("4th Nov","4th Nov","5th Nov","5th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov","8th Nov","6th Nov","6th Nov","7th Nov","7th Nov")
)
```

When you have strings that have a lot of repeated content, it is often better to write them using `paste`.  Your date string can be created more consisely using

```
paste(c(4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 6, 6, 7, 7), "th Nov", sep = "")
```

Finally, if you want to do any kind of analysis with dates, you'll want to store them in one of the many date formats.  For this, you're best not bothering with the "th", but keep the dates in a form that's easy for computers to parse, like "dd/mm/yyyy".  Then call `strptime`.